# Owl.Carousel ação dos botões NAV

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Galeria duplicada do Owl.Carousel faz com que ***nav*** personalizada mova a quantidade de galerias invés de 1 posição por vez.

A *Nav* padrão funciona normalmente andando de 1 em 1 posição.

Já na Nav personalizada a quantidade de abas interfere no andar das posições, se tenho 2 abas ele anda 2 posições, como se fosse 1 posição referente a cada aba, gostaria de saber como eu poderia resolver isso, mantendo as abas e fazendo a nav Personalizada andar apenas 1 posição por aba.

Ex imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```js
  function mostra(theId){
    var theArray= new Array('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6');
    for(i=0; i<theArray.length; i++){
     if(theArray[i] == theId){
      document.getElementById(theId).style.display='block';
     }else{
      document.getElementById(theArray[i]).style.display='none';
     }
    }
  }
  
  //Função Owl.Carousel.
  $(document).ready(function(){

     var owl = $('.owl-carousel'); // cria uma váriável para o elemento
     owl.owlCarousel({
     loop:false,
     margin:10,
     autoWidth:true,
     nav:false,
     dots:false,
     onInitialized: function(){
     $('.conteudocaixas').css('height', $('.conteudocaixas:eq(0)').outerHeight()+'px');
      
    $('.button_cx1').click(function() {
     owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [1300]);
    })
    // Go to the next item
    $('.button_cx2').click(function() {
     owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel', [1300]);
    })
      
      
/*$("#navContainer .button_cx") // seleciona os botões
  .click(function(){
  
    var idx = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
    // pega o índice do botão clicado
    
    owl.trigger( (idx == 1 ? 'next' : 'prev') + '.owl.carousel');
    // atribui o evento ao devido botão
  });*/
     }
     });
});

//Função Barra Rolante.
var SETTINGS = {
navBarTravelling: false,
navBarTravelDirection: "",
 navBarTravelDistance: 150
}

var colours = {
0: "#00BFFF",
1: "#32CD32",
2: "#FF0000",
3: "#40FEFF",
4: "#14CC99",
5: "#00BAFF",
6: "#0082B2",
7: "#B25D7A",
8: "#00FF17",
9: "#006B49",
10: "#00B27A",
11: "#996B3D",
12: "#CC7014",
13: "#40FF8C",
14: "#FF3400",
15: "#ECBB5E",
16: "#ECBB0C",
17: "#B9D912",
18: "#253A93",
19: "#125FB9",
}


document.documentElement.classList.remove("no-js");
document.documentElement.classList.add("js");

// the indicator
var indicador = document.getElementById("indicador");
var trilho = document.getElementById("trilho");

// Set the indicator
moveIndicator(trilho.querySelector("[aria-selected=\"true\"]"), colours[0]);


// Handle setting the currently active link
trilhoContents.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
var links = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".trilho_classe_Link"));
links.forEach(function(item) {
 item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
})
e.target.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
// Pass the clicked item and it's colour to the move indicator function
moveIndicator(e.target, colours[links.indexOf(e.target)]);
});


// var count = 0;
function moveIndicator(item, color) {
var textPosition = item.getBoundingClientRect();
var container = trilhoContents.getBoundingClientRect().left;
var distance = textPosition.left - container;
 var scroll = trilhoContents.scrollLeft;
indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + (distance + scroll) + "px) scaleX(" + textPosition.width * 0.01 + ")";
// count = count += 100;
// indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + count + "px)";

if (color) {
    indicador.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
}

function determineOverflow(content, container) {
var containerMetrics = container.getBoundingClientRect();
var containerMetricsRight = Math.floor(containerMetrics.right);
var containerMetricsLeft = Math.floor(containerMetrics.left);
var contentMetrics = content.getBoundingClientRect();
var contentMetricsRight = Math.floor(contentMetrics.right);
var contentMetricsLeft = Math.floor(contentMetrics.left);
 if (containerMetricsLeft > contentMetricsLeft && containerMetricsRight < contentMetricsRight) {
    return "both";
} else if (contentMetricsLeft < containerMetricsLeft) {
    return "left";
} else if (contentMetricsRight > containerMetricsRight) {
    return "right";
} else {
    return "none";
}
}
```

```css
/*==================== STYLE BARRA ROLANTE ======================*/
 
 * {
  box-sizing: inherit;
 }

 .menu_horizontal {
  position: relative;
  /*padding: 0 11px;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
  .trilho_classe {
  /* Make this scrollable when needed */
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
  .js & {
   /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
   -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
   /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
   &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
   }
  }
  /* positioning context for advancers */
  position: relative;
  /*Crush the whitespace here*/
  font-size: 0;
 }

 .trilho_classe_Contents {
  float: left;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
 }

 .trilho_classe_Contents-no-transition {
  transition: none;
 }

 .trilho_classe_Link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #888;
  /*Reset the font size*/
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 44px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0 11px;
  & + & {
   border-left-color: #eee;
  }
  &[aria-selected="true"] {
   color: #111;
  }
 }

 .trilho_classe_Indicator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out;
 }
 
 /*==================== FIM STYLE BARRA ROLANTE ======================*/
 
 /*==================== STYLE CONTEÚDO ======================*/
 
  #corpo{
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 10px;

  }
  .owl-stage{
     min-width: 100%;
  }

  .conteudocaixas{
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  .imagemcaixas{
   margin-top: 5px;
   width: 12.15%;
   max-width: 170px;
   height: auto;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .position_btcx{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 6px 10px 0 0;
      float: right;
  }
  .button_cx1{
   background: #fff;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .button_cx2{
   background: #fff;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
  }
  
 
  .conteudo {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto !important;
   background: #D1D1D1;
   margin: 0 auto;
         /*display: none;*/
  }
  .conteudo p {
   margin: 20px;
  }
 
  /*==================== FIM STYLE CONTEÚDO ======================*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div id="corpo">
  
   <div class="menu_horizontal">
    <nav id="trilho" class="trilho_classe">

     

     <div id="trilhoContents" class="trilho_classe_Contents">
      
      <a onclick="mostra('item1');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link item_aba" aria-selected="true">Galeria1</a>
      <a onclick="mostra('item2');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link item_aba" aria-selected="false">Galeria2</a>
      <!--<a onclick="mostra('item3');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link item_aba" aria-selected="false">Galeria3</a>-->
      
      <span id="indicador" class="trilho_classe_Indicator" style="transform: translateX(0px) scaleX(0.965781); background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);"></span>
     </div>

     <div class="position_btcx" id="navContainer">
      <button class="button_cx1" type="button">&lt;</button>
      <button class="button_cx2" type="button">&gt;</button>
     </div>
     
    </nav>
   </div>
  
  <div id="item1" class="conteudo" style="display: block;">
   <div class="conteudocaixas owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="item2" class="conteudo" style="display: none;">
   <div class="conteudocaixas owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <!--<div id="item3" class="conteudo" style="display: none;">
   <div class="conteudocaixas owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>-->
  
 </div>
```

Obs: Na imagem tem 3 galerias e no código para simplificar um pouco eu deixei apenas duas.

Comment: Cara segundo a documentação vc pode usar o metodo `slideBy: 1` para dizer que o slide deve passar uma imagem por vez. ou por exemplo `slideBy: 3` para passar 3 imagens por vez... Aqui tem a documentação https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

Comment: sim, ele tem como padrão o "slideBy:1" e o erro é que esse 1 é como valido para cada galeria que eu adicionar, como se ele contasse 1 para cada uma.